# Formatting data extracted by entities

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In a table view managed by core data I have a date field. Now I need to get it, but I got errors in the output.

```
for (FesteGruppo *festeGruppoEntity in arrayController_.selectedObjects) {
                NSString *valorePrimaFesta=[festeGruppoEntity.data descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%w" timeZone:nil locale:nil];
                int prova = [valorePrimaFesta intValue];

                if (prova==0) {
                    --domenica;
                } else if (prova==1){
                    --lunedi;
                } else if (prova==2){
                    --martedi;
                } else if (prova==3){
                    --mercoledi;
                } else if (prova==4){
                    --giovedi;
                } else if (prova==5){
                    --venerdi;
                } else if (prova==6){
                    --sabato;
                }

                NSLog(@"The entity's date is %@", festeGruppoEntity.data);
                NSLog(@"The date number is %i", prova);
            }
```

I put this date: 10/04/2012 (dd/MM/yyyy), but I get this result:
The entity's date is 2013-04-09 22:00:00 +0000
The date number is 3.
I need to get the same date I have entered above, how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're in a time zone which is GMT+02:00.  I'm also guessing you either entered a date in 2013 or you mis-copied the output.  A date of 10/04/2012 with no time information is, in your time zone, "2012-04-10 00:00:00 +0200" which is the same as "2012-04-09 22:00:00 +0000". `NSDate` logs itself in GMT+00:00.

So, I think you'll have to pass a real value, not `nil`, for the `timeZone:` parameter of the `-descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:` method.